# UserControl's DataContext: set it to viewmodel directly

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a wpf usercontrol and a correspondent viewmodel (ChamberVm) made for it.

In viewmodel there is a property named 'UnitStatus'
But I got binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnitStatus' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1814504727)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnitStatus; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1814504727); target element is 'VacGram' (Name='sysdgm'); target property is 'UnitStatus' (type 'KeyValuePair`2')
```

I have noted the mistake might be about DataContext setting in the header part of my control:

```
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:dgm="clr-namespace:VacSym;assembly=VacSymDgm"             
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:VacViews"    
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="400"
             DataContext="ChamberVm">
    <Grid Name="gridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <DockPanel x:Name="pnlDgm" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <dgm:VacGram x:Name="sysdgm" UnitStatus="{Binding UnitStatus}" DiagramFile="{Binding DiagramFile}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DockPanel>

       . . .
```

I want to know:

1, why this is not correct (?)

```
    DataContext="ChamberVm"
```

2, what the 'String' means in the error message:

```
    ...not found on 'object' ''String'
```

Ting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
DataContext="ChamberVm"
```

assigns the string `"ChamberVm"` to the DataContext property.

In order to assign an instance of the ChamberVm class, you would have to write the following, with an appropriate namespace prefix:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <v:ChamberVm/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

---

In general, you should avoid to explicitly assign the DataContext property at all.

You would instead put the UserControl in a DataTemplate that is applied to e.g. a ContentControl that has a ChamberVm object assigned to its Content property. The DataContext of the UserControl would then be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Your DataContext** is a string `"ChamberVm"`, not an object.

That's why you can't find `UnitStatus`.

```xml
<!-- Just set string in DataContext -->
<Window DataContext="ChamberVm">

</Window>
```

ChamberVm is `string` right.

So, of course, there is no UnitStatus (object) in DataContext (string).

And DataContext property is `object` type.

```cs
// DependencyProperty
public object DataContext { get; set; }

// You can put anything in.
```

It's a mistake that everyone makes often.

## Anyway, you use DataContext in two main ways.

(To your liking)

#### 1. DataContext Direct Binding in XAML.

```xml
<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VacViews.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ChamberVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

You must declare the namespace of your view model at the top first. `xmlns:vm="your namespace"`

And open DataContext to declare the view model you created. This is to create an instance and assign it to DataContext.

#### 2. Set Create Instance in Behind.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Your ViewModel set in DataContext.
        DataContext = new ChamberVm();
    }
}
```

Creating a 'view model' instance within the constructor block is the most impressive position.

Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.